# httpwebrequest encoding error

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Im getting a strange error sometimes on my httpwebrequests.

Error im getting:

```
ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
'' is not a supported encoding name.
```

Code i am running:

```
            try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Timeout = 3000;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 3000;
            request.Proxy = new WebProxy(p.ToString(), true);

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Encoding responseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), responseEncoding))
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // do stuff
                }
            }


        }
        catch (WebException wexc1)
        {
            if (wexc1.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
                response.Close();
        }
```

It doesent happend all the time its like 1 out of 500 requests. It feels like the code is unable to determine the actual encoding.. but how would i handle this?

The error currently makes the application crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the exception is thrown in the line:

```
Encoding responseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
```

As a quick advice I would suggest setting `Encoding.UTF8` or `response.ContentEncoding` as the encoding of the stream and not relying on `response.CharacterSet()`.

CharacterSet is a WebName (e.g. `Encoding.UTF8.WebName`), not a proper name of the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Do you explicitly set the encoding of the Request? Something like

```
Response.Charset = "windows-1252";
```

in the page accessed by the WebRequest? CharacterSet is not always consistent if it is not explicitly set by the web server.

You could also check for cases when CharacterSet is empty and substitute a default value, likely 'windows-1252' or whatever the appropriate encoding for your web server is. Example:

```
string charset = response.CharacterSet; 
if charset == "")
{
    charset = "windows-1252";
}
Encoding responseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(charset);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works

```
    private string GetHtmlFromResponse(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        string sFicha = null;
        using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            Encoding eCodificacion = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, eCodificacion);
            sFicha = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }

        return sFicha;
    }
```

I was downloading a spanish page and the characters á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ were lost. With this code, I get the right text.